# This action is unauthorized in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

I'm using spatie/laravel-permission and when I add my permission to my api route, I'm getting

```
message: "This action is unauthorized.
```

but my user does have permission

My route

```
Route::get('/customer/items', [ CustomerController::class, 'getItems'])->middleware('can:customer');
```

My CustomerController

```
public function getItems()
{
    $items = Item::all();

    return [
        'items' => $items
    ];
}
```

Comment: Add your function also

Comment: I've updated my question to add the function

Comment: This means user doesn't have enough permission then . Check all the permissions of user

Answer (score 0):

I was this problem because my guard was auth:api

```
Route::prefix('coin')->middleware(['auth:api','can:manageCoins'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [CoinController::class, 'getAllPagination']);
});
```

in role table and permission table filed guard_name = web

I change all guard_name to api

fixed it middleware `can` work for guard api

note : run this command `php artisan optimize:clear`